# Using "awk" to find a string between two other specific strings:

Tags: bash, awk, grep, pipe, ksh

I have a large output of text that'll include several lines like this:

```
sending:WHATIWANT:output
```

How would I use `awk` to make it so that this output would ONLY include `WHATIWANT` on each line?

edit: there is a changing amount of text before and after `WHATIWANT` so something like `awk -F: '{print $2}'` would not always work

Comment: `awk -F: '{print $2}'`

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific, there is someoutput before and after it that may change what order the string I want is.

     stuffstuffstuffsending:WHATIWANT:outputstuffstuffstuff

Comment: If `:` is delimiter then `WHATIWANT` is still `$2` in `stuffstuffstuffsending:WHATIWANT:outputstuffstuffstuff`

Comment: my apologies by there may be an undetermined number of colons in "stuffstuffstuff"

Comment: better [edit] showing a more realistic sample input. Otherwise it is quite complicated to know what you want.

Comment: Sorry we are not mind readers, you should show few sample inputs with expected outputs.

Comment: try `sed 's/^.\+sending:\(\w\+\):output$/\1/g' input.txt`. this is assuming all lines end with output ( need more info on this to post a proper answer )

Comment: Please show more. I am tempted to `grep -o WHATIWANT input.txt` or the sed command given by @amdixon .

Answer (score 0):

From what you mention in the comments, this should do it:

```
perl -n -e'/sending:([^:]+):output/ && print $1' input_file
```

This runs a simple regex match line-by-line, capturing the interesting part and then printing it. It assumes that `WHATIWANT` does not contain the character `:`

If for some reason you absolutely must use `awk(1)`, then I think you don't have much choice but to do this:

```
awk -F: '{ for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) if ($(i-1) == "sending" && $(i+1) == "output") print $i }' input_file
```

It basically splits each line by `:` and iterates through every field, comparing the left and right fields until it finds one that is between `sending` and `output`. Again, it assumes that `WHATIWANT` does not have a `:`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use sed?

```
echo "asfasfdsf__sending:WHATIWANT:output__asdfadas" | sed -n 's/.*sending\:\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\:output.*/\1/p'
```

Gives you "WHATIWANT"